# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘tuple’ with no type

Tags: c++, g++, tuples, std, std-pair

When trying to compile a simple class (`g++ myclass.cpp`), I get the following error:

> ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘tuple’ with no type

I searched for this problem, and in most cases people seemed to forget `std::` or including `<tuple>` in the header. But I have both. Here is my code:

**myclass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS
#define MYCLASS

#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class MyClass {
    std::tuple<bool, int, int> my_method();
};

#endif
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

using namespace std;

tuple<bool, int, int> MyClass::my_method() {
    return make_tuple(true, 1, 1);
}
```

If I do the same using `pair` instead, leaving out the second `int` and including `<set>`, it works.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Here is the full output:

> $ g++ myclass.cpp -o prog
>       In file included from myclass.cpp:1:
>       myclass.h:7: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘tuple’ with no type
>       myclass.h:7: error: invalid use of ‘::’
>       myclass.h:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
>       myclass.cpp:5: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion 
>   before ‘<’ token
>
> $ g++ --version
>       i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658)
>       (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Comment: Did you specify `-std=c++11` when compiling the code?

Comment: `using namespace std;` - What a blasphemy!

Comment: Can't reproduce this error. Are you sure that you used exactly this code? You should mark the exact line g++ reported.

Comment: My compiler doesn't seem to support C++11: `$ g++ -std=c++11 myclass.cpp -o prog
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"`. I'm using `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1`. Would you recommend trying to change compiler or is there an alternative to `tuple` for older compilers?

Comment: Uh, I don't see any `#include <tuple>` in your header.

Comment: Consider upgrading GCC, perhaps by downloading its source code (`gcc-8.3`) and compiling that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

GCC 4.2.1 shipped with every mac is outdated. It will not recognize the C++11.

You need to compile your code using: c++ instead of g++ which calls clang, which is the officially updated compiler on mac.

```
c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ myclass.cpp -o prog
```

You are required to link against libc++ which is clang lib which knows about c++11 features instead of the default libstdc++ used by gcc.

Comment: Is there any reason, why on my 2012 Mac (OS X 10.8.2, latest Xcode) I would have such an old GCC? (I didn't install it myself, Xcode probably did). I'm afraid of breaking my environment if I try to update.

Comment: No it is normal. Apple has moved to clang and dropped gcc but they keep it not to break retro compatibility.

Comment: It is likely that you will break your environnement if you try to update gcc. Use clang, it is faster anyway ...

Answer (score 5):

Update! We're on GCC 4.7 these days.

GCC 4.2.1 is from all the way back on [18th July, 2007](http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html). There is only a remote chance that it supports *any* features from what became C++11.

That said, it may provide some in `std::tr1` (i.e. `std::tr1::tuple<T1, T2, ...>`), which is where some of the C++11 features lived in the time before standardisation, though off the top of my head these were introduced to GCC only in 4.4.

Comment: Is there any reason, why on my 2012 Mac (OS X 10.8.2, latest Xcode) I would have such an old GCC? (I didn't install it myself, Xcode probably did). I'm afraid of breaking my environment if I try to update.

Comment: @Jawap: Beats me. Ask the packaging team.

Comment: It is not a good idea to update gcc on mac. It will break compatibility. You can have a gcc but not in /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: @Kikhos: out of interest, compatibility of what? What kind of thing is it in OSX that depends on /usr/bin/gcc being 4.2.1?

Answer (score 4):

With gcc 4.2, `tuple` was in namespace `std::tr1`. You must include `<tr1/tuple>` and specify your method more or less like this

```
#ifndef MYCLASS
#define MYCLASS

#include <tr1/tuple>

class MyClass {
    std::tr1::tuple<bool, int, int> my_method();
};

#endif
```

Although, as others already suggested, updating to a more recent gcc might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `-std=c++11` (or, for older versions of `g++` the `-std=c++0x`) option and add a simicolon after the expression in the member function the code compiles. If this doesn't work you might have a version which only defines `tuple` in namespace `std::tr1` (it seems, the implementation provides a `<tuple>` header, though, because there is no error about `<tuple>` not being found).